# Photo grid not wrapping properly - Wordpress theme is using bootstrap

Tags: css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I am using Wordpress theme GTBuilder. The project aspect of it, when set to tab style, is wrapping my project's featured images incorrectly. Any one know how to adjust this/why this is happening/ or is a bootstrap master and can help me adjust the columns to be three full rows?
It looks like this theme uses bootstrap, but I'm not sure why it's not working properly... 
[image]

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
 <article id="post-10" class="post-10 page type-page status-publish hentry">
        <div class="page-content content-clear">
        <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid vc_custom_1549388643425 vc_column-gap-2 vc_row-o-equal-height vc_row-flex">
            <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12">
                <div class="vc_column-inner ">
                    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                        <div class="project-page">
                         <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <h2 class="project-grid-title">Latest Projects</h2>
                       </div>   
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                           <div class="tab-list-area">            
                            <ul>
                             <li class="active"><a href="#project-all" data-toggle="tab">All</a></li>
           <li role="presentation" class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#project-casinos" aria-expanded="false">Casinos</a></li>
           <li role="presentation" class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#project-condominiums" aria-expanded="false">Condominiums</a></li>
           <li role="presentation" class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#project-energy" aria-expanded="false">Energy</a></li>
           <li role="presentation" class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#project-goverment-municipalities" aria-expanded="false">Goverment/Municipalities</a></li>
           <li role="presentation" class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#project-hospitals" aria-expanded="false">Hospitals</a></li>
           <li role="presentation" class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#project-mixed-use" aria-expanded="false">Mixed Use</a></li>
           <li role="presentation" class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#project-residential" aria-expanded="false">Residential</a></li>
           <li role="presentation" class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#project-retail" aria-expanded="false">Retail</a></li>
           <li role="presentation" class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#project-schools" aria-expanded="false">Schools</a></li>
           <li role="presentation" class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#project-stadiums_museums" aria-expanded="false">Stadiums/Museums</a></li>
                                </ul>

                           </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                           <div class="tab-content-area">
                            <div class="tab-content">
                             <div id="project-all" class="tab-pane active">
                              <div class="latest-project-page">
                   <div class="single-project">
                                         <a><img alt="Santana Row - CA" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/SantanaRow-Retail-280x230.jpg"></a>
                                     <div class="project-overley">
                                  <div class="content">
                                   <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/santana-row-ca/">Santana Row - CA</a></h3>
                                   <p>Retail</p>     
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="link">
                                   <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/santana-row-ca/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                  </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                       <div class="single-project">
                                                <a><img alt="Sacramento Downtown Plaza - CA" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/SacPlaza-280x230.jpg"></a>
                                                <div class="project-overley">
                                                    <div class="content">
                                                        <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/sacramento-downtown-plaza-ca/">Sacramento Downtown Plaza - CA</a></h3>
                                                        <p>Mixed Use</p>     
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="link">
                                                        <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/sacramento-downtown-plaza-ca/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                       <div class="single-project">
                                                <a><img alt="Kansas City Chiefs Stadium" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/ChiefsStad-280x230.jpg"></a>
                                            <div class="project-overley">
                                                <div class="content">
                                                    <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/kansas-city-chiefs-stadium/">Kansas City Chiefs Stadium</a></h3>
                                                    <p>Stadiums/Museums</p>     
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="link">
                                                    <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/kansas-city-chiefs-stadium/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                   <div class="single-project">
                                            <a><img alt="Bernalillo County Courthouse - NM" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Bernalillo-County-Courthouse-280x230.jpg"></a>
                                                <div class="project-overley">
                                                    <div class="content">
                                                        <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/bernalillo-county-courthouse-nm/">Bernalillo County Courthouse - NM</a></h3>
                                                        <p>Goverment/Municipalities</p>     
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="link">
                                                        <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/bernalillo-county-courthouse-nm/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                   <div class="single-project">
                                            <a><img alt="Greenland Metropolis, CA" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/GreenlandMetroCA-Condo-280x230.jpg"></a>
                                                <div class="project-overley">
                                  <div class="content">
                                                        <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/greenland-metropolis-ca/">Greenland Metropolis, CA</a></h3>
                                                        <p>Condominiums</p>     
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="link">
                                                        <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/greenland-metropolis-ca/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                   <div class="single-project">
                                            <a><img alt="Harlem NY Commercial Retail" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/harlemny-retail-1-280x229.jpg"></a>
                                                <div class="project-overley">
                                                    <div class="content">
                                                        <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/harlem-ny-commercial-retail/">Harlem NY Commercial Retail</a></h3>
                                                        <p>Retail</p>     
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="link">
                                                        <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/harlem-ny-commercial-retail/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
       <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Hermann High School, MO" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/hermannhighschool-mo-1-280x229.jpg"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/hermann-high-school-mo/">Hermann High School, MO</a></h3>
       <p>Schools</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/hermann-high-school-mo/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
       <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Hawaii Military Communities" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/HIMiliatryCommunity-280x230.jpg"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/hawaii-military-communities/">Hawaii Military Communities</a></h3>
       <p>Residential</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/hawaii-military-communities/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
       <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Dallas Cowboy's Headquarters Frisco" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/DallasCowboysStad-280x230.jpg"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/dallas-cowboys-headquarters-frisco/">Dallas Cowboy's Headquarters Frisco</a></h3>
       <p>Stadiums/Museums</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/dallas-cowboys-headquarters-frisco/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
       <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Sugarhouse Casino Philadelphia" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Sugarhouse-Casino-Phily-280x230.jpg"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/sugarhouse-casino-philadelphia/">Sugarhouse Casino Philadelphia</a></h3>
       <p>Casinos</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/sugarhouse-casino-philadelphia/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
       <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Arizona Solar Field" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/SolarField-AZ-280x230.jpg"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/long-road/">Arizona Solar Field</a></h3>
       <p>Energy</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/long-road/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
       <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Bio Energy Plant, KS" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/bioenergyks-1-280x229.jpg"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/complex-construction/">Bio Energy Plant, KS</a></h3>
       <p>Energy</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/complex-construction/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
       <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="San Francisco General Hospital" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/SanFrancisco-General-Hospital-280x230.png"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/guest-room/">San Francisco General Hospital</a></h3>
       <p>Hospitals</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/guest-room/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
       <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="St Francis Health System Tulsa" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/StFrancis-Health-System-Tulsa-280x230.png"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/eye-catching-room/">St Francis Health System Tulsa</a></h3>
       <p>Hospitals</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/eye-catching-room/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
       <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Des Plaines Casino Chicago" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Des-Plaines-Casino-Chicago-280x230.png"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/decorated-room/">Des Plaines Casino Chicago</a></h3>
       <p>Casinos</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/decorated-room/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
     </div>
      <div id="project-casinos" class="tab-pane">
       <div class="latest-project-page">
            <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Sugarhouse Casino Philadelphia" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Sugarhouse-Casino-Phily-280x230.jpg"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/sugarhouse-casino-philadelphia/">Sugarhouse Casino Philadelphia</a></h3>
       <p>Casinos</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/sugarhouse-casino-philadelphia/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
       <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Des Plaines Casino Chicago" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Des-Plaines-Casino-Chicago-280x230.png"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/decorated-room/">Des Plaines Casino Chicago</a></h3>
       <p>Casinos</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/decorated-room/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
          </div>
      </div>
           <div id="project-condominiums" class="tab-pane">
       <div class="latest-project-page">
            <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Greenland Metropolis, CA" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/GreenlandMetroCA-Condo-280x230.jpg"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/greenland-metropolis-ca/">Greenland Metropolis, CA</a></h3>
       <p>Condominiums</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/greenland-metropolis-ca/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
          </div>
      </div>
           <div id="project-energy" class="tab-pane">
       <div class="latest-project-page">
            <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Arizona Solar Field" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/SolarField-AZ-280x230.jpg"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/long-road/">Arizona Solar Field</a></h3>
       <p>Energy</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/long-road/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
       <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Bio Energy Plant, KS" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/bioenergyks-1-280x229.jpg"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/complex-construction/">Bio Energy Plant, KS</a></h3>
       <p>Energy</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/complex-construction/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
          </div>
      </div>
           <div id="project-goverment-municipalities" class="tab-pane">
       <div class="latest-project-page">
            <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Bernalillo County Courthouse - NM" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Bernalillo-County-Courthouse-280x230.jpg"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/bernalillo-county-courthouse-nm/">Bernalillo County Courthouse - NM</a></h3>
       <p>Goverment/Municipalities</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/bernalillo-county-courthouse-nm/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
          </div>
      </div>
           <div id="project-hospitals" class="tab-pane">
       <div class="latest-project-page">
            <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="San Francisco General Hospital" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/SanFrancisco-General-Hospital-280x230.png"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/guest-room/">San Francisco General Hospital</a></h3>
       <p>Hospitals</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/guest-room/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
       <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="St Francis Health System Tulsa" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/StFrancis-Health-System-Tulsa-280x230.png"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/eye-catching-room/">St Francis Health System Tulsa</a></h3>
       <p>Hospitals</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/eye-catching-room/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
          </div>
      </div>
           <div id="project-mixed-use" class="tab-pane">
       <div class="latest-project-page">
            <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Sacramento Downtown Plaza - CA" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/SacPlaza-280x230.jpg"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/sacramento-downtown-plaza-ca/">Sacramento Downtown Plaza - CA</a></h3>
       <p>Mixed Use</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/sacramento-downtown-plaza-ca/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
          </div>
      </div>
           <div id="project-residential" class="tab-pane">
       <div class="latest-project-page">
            <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Hawaii Military Communities" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/HIMiliatryCommunity-280x230.jpg"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/hawaii-military-communities/">Hawaii Military Communities</a></h3>
       <p>Residential</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/hawaii-military-communities/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
          </div>
      </div>
           <div id="project-retail" class="tab-pane">
       <div class="latest-project-page">
            <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Santana Row - CA" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/SantanaRow-Retail-280x230.jpg"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/santana-row-ca/">Santana Row - CA</a></h3>
       <p>Retail</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/santana-row-ca/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
       <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Harlem NY Commercial Retail" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/harlemny-retail-1-280x229.jpg"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/harlem-ny-commercial-retail/">Harlem NY Commercial Retail</a></h3>
       <p>Retail</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/harlem-ny-commercial-retail/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
          </div>
      </div>
           <div id="project-schools" class="tab-pane">
       <div class="latest-project-page">
            <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Hermann High School, MO" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/hermannhighschool-mo-1-280x229.jpg"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/hermann-high-school-mo/">Hermann High School, MO</a></h3>
       <p>Schools</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/hermann-high-school-mo/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
          </div>
      </div>
           <div id="project-stadiums_museums" class="tab-pane">
       <div class="latest-project-page">
            <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Kansas City Chiefs Stadium" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/ChiefsStad-280x230.jpg"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/kansas-city-chiefs-stadium/">Kansas City Chiefs Stadium</a></h3>
       <p>Stadiums/Museums</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/kansas-city-chiefs-stadium/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
       <div class="single-project">
     <a><img alt="Dallas Cowboy's Headquarters Frisco" src="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/DallasCowboysStad-280x230.jpg"></a>
     <div class="project-overley">
      <div class="content">
       <h3><a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/dallas-cowboys-headquarters-frisco/">Dallas Cowboy's Headquarters Frisco</a></h3>
       <p>Stadiums/Museums</p>     
      </div>
      <div class="link">
       <a href="http://10.4.1.79/www.wrapupsolutions.com/projects/dallas-cowboys-headquarters-frisco/"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
                </div>
         </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>           
  </div>
 </div>
</div></div></div></div></div>
        </div>
    </article> 
</div>
```

Comment: where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

With the lack of code, etc. Its kinda hard to know whats happening.

But judging by the screenshot, seems like one of the photos' height is smaller and the elements are floating, so it's doing normal float behaviour, filling the spaces.

A quick fix would be to make all the photos have the same height.